# JSON move child keys up one level

Tags: python, json

I have a Python script that parses a JSON file like below:

```
[
  {
    "_index": "bulletins",
    "_type": "bulletin",
    "_id": "OPENWRT-SA-000001",
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
      "lastseen": "2016-09-26T15:45:23",
      "references": [
        "http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2015-3193",
      ],
      "affectedPackage": [
        {
          "OS": "OpenWrt",
          "OSVersion": "15.05",
          "packageVersion": "9.9.8-P3-1",
          "packageFilename": "UNKNOWN",
          "arch": "all",
          "packageName": "bind",
          "operator": "lt"
        }
      ],
      "edition": 1,
      "description": "value in here,
      "reporter": "OpenWrt Project",
      "published": "2016-01-24T13:33:41",
      "title": "bind: Security update (4 CVEs)",
      "type": "openwrt",
      "bulletinFamily": "unix",
      "cvelist": [
        "CVE-2015-8704",
      ],
      "modified": "2016-01-24T13:33:41",
      "id": "OPENWRT-SA-000001",
      "href": "https://lists.openwrt.org/pipermail/openwrt-security-announce/2016-January/000001.html",
      "cvss": {
        "score": 7.1,
        "vector": "AV:NETWORK/AC:MEDIUM/Au:NONE/C:NONE/I:NONE/A:COMPLETE/"
      }
    },
    "sort": [
      34872
    ]
  },
```

I have removed some of the values to keep the post shorter but leaving some in to try to keep the structure.

I want to take all sub keys from the `_source` key and move them up to the same level as `_source` and then delete the `_source` key.

My code to parse the JSON is:

```
import json
import logging
import logging.handlers
import os
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient


def import_json(mongo_server,mongo_port, vuln_folder):
    try:
        logging.info('Connecting to MongoDB')
        client = MongoClient(mongo_server, mongo_port)
        db = client['vuln_sets']
        coll = db['vulnerabilities']
        logging.info('Connected to MongoDB')
        basepath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        filepath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(basepath, ".."))
        archive_filepath = filepath + vuln_folder
        filedir = os.chdir(archive_filepath)
        file_count = 0
        for item in os.listdir(filedir):
            if item.endswith('.json'):
                file_name = os.path.abspath(item)
                with open(item, 'r') as currentfile:
                    vuln_counter = 0
                    duplicate_count = 0
                    logging.info('Currently processing ' + item)
                    file_count +=1
                    json_data = currentfile.read()
                    vuln_content = json.loads(json_data)
                    for vuln in vuln_content:
                        try:
                            del vuln['_type']
                            coll.insert(vuln, continue_on_error=True)
                            vuln_counter +=1
                        except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError:
                            duplicate_count +=1

                logging.info('Added ' + str(vuln_counter) + ' vulnerabilities for ' + item)
                logging.info('Found ' + str(duplicate_count) + ' duplicate records!')
                os.remove(file_name)
        logging.info('Processed ' + str(file_count) + ' files')
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e)
```

Which you can see already deletes one key that is not needed but that key has no needed data where as I need the sub keys from _source. I am not sure on the best way to achieve this, whether it would be programmatically correct to just re-create the JSON file with the new info but I need to keep the order of the keys and structure apart from moving the sub keys up one level.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dictionary `update()` function to achieve what you're trying to do, but it's important to note that dictionaries don't have an "order of the keys" - see: [Key Order in Python Dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629023/key-order-in-python-dictionaries).

Here's an example of one way to do this, starting with a dictionary definition.

```
d = {
    "_index": "bulletins",
    "_type": "bulletin",
    "_id": "OPENWRT-SA-000001",
    "_score": None,
    "_source": {
        "lastseen": "2016-09-26T15:45:23",
        "references": [
            "http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2015-3193",
        ],
        "affectedPackage": [
            {
              "OS": "OpenWrt",
              "OSVersion": "15.05",
              "packageVersion": "9.9.8-P3-1",
              "packageFilename": "UNKNOWN",
              "arch": "all",
              "packageName": "bind",
              "operator": "lt"
            }
        ],
        "edition": 1,
        "description": "value in here",
        "reporter": "OpenWrt Project",
        "published": "2016-01-24T13:33:41",
        "title": "bind: Security update (4 CVEs)",
        "type": "openwrt",
        "bulletinFamily": "unix",
        "cvelist": [
            "CVE-2015-8704",
        ],
        "modified": "2016-01-24T13:33:41",
        "id": "OPENWRT-SA-000001",
        "href": "https://lists.openwrt.org/pipermail/openwrt-security-announce/2016-January/000001.html",
        "cvss": {
            "score": 7.1,
            "vector":     "AV:NETWORK/AC:MEDIUM/Au:NONE/C:NONE/I:NONE/A:COMPLETE/"
        }
    }
}

# create a new dictionary with everything except the key "_source"
new_d = {key: d[key] for key in d if key != '_source'}

# add the keys/values from "_source" to new dictionary
new_d.update(d['_source'])  # This will overwriting any existing keys
```

The output of new_d:

```
{'_id': 'OPENWRT-SA-000001',
 '_index': 'bulletins',
 '_score': None,
 '_type': 'bulletin',
 'affectedPackage': [{'OS': 'OpenWrt',
   'OSVersion': '15.05',
   'arch': 'all',
   'operator': 'lt',
   'packageFilename': 'UNKNOWN',
   'packageName': 'bind',
   'packageVersion': '9.9.8-P3-1'}],
 'bulletinFamily': 'unix',
 'cvelist': ['CVE-2015-8704'],
 'cvss': {
   'score': 7.1,
   'vector': 'AV:NETWORK/AC:MEDIUM/Au:NONE/C:NONE/I:NONE/A:COMPLETE/'},
 'description': 'value in here',
 'edition': 1,
 'href': 'https://lists.openwrt.org/pipermail/openwrt-security-announce/2016-January/000001.html',
 'id': 'OPENWRT-SA-000001',
 'lastseen': '2016-09-26T15:45:23',
 'modified': '2016-01-24T13:33:41',
 'published': '2016-01-24T13:33:41',
 'references': ['http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2015-
3193'],
 'reporter': 'OpenWrt Project',
 'title': 'bind: Security update (4 CVEs)',
 'type': 'openwrt'}
```

Comment: I tried to implement this in my existing code by changing it to: `d = currentfile.read()
                    new_json = {key: d[key] for key in d if key != '_source'}
                    new_json.update(d['_source'])
                    vuln_content = json.loads(new_json)` but this just gives an error of `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: That's because you assigned the output of `currentfile.read()` to `d`, so `d` is a string. I think what  you meant to do was something like `d = json.loads(currentfile.read())`

Comment: You may also find this useful: [Delete an item from a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844672/delete-an-item-from-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by using the following code:

```
for vuln in vuln_content:
                    try:
                        del vuln['_type']
                        new_vuln = {key: vuln[key] for key in vuln if key != '_source'}
                        new_vuln.update(vuln['_source'])
                        coll.insert(new_vuln, continue_on_error=True)
                        vuln_counter +=1
                    except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError:
                        duplicate_count +=1
```