# How can i make 'image' key the first?

Tags: python, dictionary, flask

```
labels = app.config["LABELS"]
```

then `print(labels)`

```
   [{'name': '', 'image': '34-4.png', 'xMax': '2287', 'xMin': '2102', 'yMin': '53', 'id': '1', 'yMax': '110'},
    {'name': '', 'image': '34-4.png', 'xMax': '2414', 'xMin': '2299', 'yMin': '80', 'id': '2', 'yMax': '118'},
    {'name': '', 'image': '34-4.png', 'xMax': '2193', 'xMin': '2138', 'yMin': '128', 'id': '3', 'yMax': '140'}]
```

The actual list is way bigger , how can i order these values so the dictionary starts with image instead of name, and for some reason they always start with name, i did check previous answers on here like [Key Order in Python Dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629023/key-order-in-python-dictionaries) ,`orderedDict` but i'm not inserting them that way, i already have them and want to change they are(their order)

Comment: why do you need that? for `json` serializing?

Comment: Possible duplicated [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: It won't have any effect code wise on later processing stages but i just want to see the image `image` first as simple as that.

Comment: Do you care what happens to the order of the other keys in each sub-dictionary?

Comment: No i don't i just want image first.

Comment: Ok. Do you understand how to use the solution of FHTMitchell?

Comment: Trying to still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionaries (unless you are running the beta version of python 3.7) are not ordered. They have no concept of order, and can yield values in any order which depending on your implementation may change with each iteration.

You either must use a list of 2-tuples or an OrderedDict. In order to change a dict into an ordered dict, use

```
od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(labels[index].items(), key=f))
```

where `f` is a function taking a single `(key, value)` tuple argument defining how you would like to sort. If all you want is the `'image'` key to be first, use

`f = lambda t: t[0] != 'image'`

which will return `False` (aka `0`) for `image` and `True` (aka `1`) for every other key.

Edit:

So with your `labels` as defined above do:

```
for index, label in enumerate(labels):
    labels[index] = collections.OrderedDict(
              sorted(label.items(), key=lambda t: t[0] != 'image'))
```

Outputs `labels`:

```
[OrderedDict([('image', '34-4.png'),
              ('name', ''),
              ('xMax', '2287'),
              ('xMin', '2102'),
              ('yMin', '53'),
              ('id', '1'),
              ('yMax', '110')]),
 OrderedDict([('image', '34-4.png'),
              ('name', ''),
              ('xMax', '2414'),
              ('xMin', '2299'),
              ('yMin', '80'),
              ('id', '2'),
              ('yMax', '118')]),
 OrderedDict([('image', '34-4.png'),
              ('name', ''),
              ('xMax', '2193'),
              ('xMin', '2138'),
              ('yMin', '128'),
              ('id', '3'),
              ('yMax', '140')])]
```

Comment: FWIW, plain dict retains insertion order in Python 3.6.0+ (it didn't in the 3.6 beta).

Comment: @PM2Ring I know :), but I don't want to confuse the matter any further.

Comment: i imported collections, what should i replace `index` with tho

Comment: @user9686018 The index of `labels`......    So `0`, `1`, `2`, ... etc. for each one in turn. see my edit

Comment: Correct i have had the same output but what i was thinking of is keeping them as lists of dictionaries like i showed an example of in my question, without adding ordereddict in the output or make them tuples shape,.

Comment: Which version of python are you on? `import sys; print sys.version` if its not greater than 3.6.0 the answer is you can't. What's wrong with an `OrderedDict` anyway? It is a subclass of `dict` and will do everything a `dict` does.