# How to sort Dictionary Keys in Python

Tags: python

i have this code:

```
myDict = {}
myDict['Hello'] = 's'
myDict['Hallo'] = 'a'
myDict['Test'] = 'b'
myDict['Buy'] = 'hoo'
myDict['Hehe'] = 'kkk'

print(list(myDict.keys()))
```

and it return random, like :

```
['Hallo','Buy','Hehe','Test,'Hello']
```

what I want is  :

```
['Hello','Hallo','Test','Buy','Hehe']
```

'Hello' is first ,'Hallo' is second, 'Test' is Third, 'Buy' is Fourth, 'Hehe' is Fifth

it's very important because i want to make csv file :

```
with open('names.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = list(myDict.keys())

    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter = ";")

    writer.writeheader()

    writer.writerow(myDict)
```

Comment: This will work as is in Python 3.6+, otherwise use a `collections.OrderedDict`

Comment: Python behaves differently based on version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629023/key-order-in-python-dictionaries) questions:

**Python 3.7+**
In Python 3.7.0 the insertion-order preservation nature of dict objects has been declared to be an official part of the Python language spec. Therefore, you can depend on it.

**Python 3.6 (CPython)**
As of Python 3.6, for the CPython implementation of Python, dictionaries maintain insertion order by default. This is considered an implementation detail though; you should still use collections.OrderedDict if you want insertion ordering that's guaranteed across other implementations of Python.

**Python <3.6**
Use the collections.OrderedDict class when you need a dict that remembers the order of items inserted.

Answer (score 2):

Use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes).
And just to remind you, since python 3.6 dict is insertion ordered. What version do you use ?

```
# regular unsorted dictionary
d = {'banana': 3, 'apple': 4, 'pear': 1, 'orange': 2}

# dictionary sorted by key
OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
OrderedDict([('apple', 4), ('banana', 3), ('orange', 2), 
('pear', 1)]) 

# dictionary sorted by value
OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))
OrderedDict([('pear', 1), ('orange', 2), ('banana', 3), 
('apple', 4)])
```