# Combining 2 arrays into a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have an array of strings (`a1`): `["a", "b", "c"]`

And another (`a2`) that looks like this:

```
["1,20,300", "2,10,300", "3,40,300", "1, 20, 300, 4000"]
```

The wanted end result is:

```
{"a": [1,2,3,1], "b": [20, 10, 40, 20], "c": [300, 300, 300, 4000] }
```

It is safe to assume that `a2[n].split(',')` will always give me the items in the correct order, i.e. the order of `["a", "b", "c"]`, just as in the example.

With this in mind, is it possible not having to loop twice and/or **not** having to assume the order of keys in a dictionary is consistent?

My solution would be:

```
a1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
a2 = ["1,20,300", "2,10,300", "3,40,300"]

result = {}

for i in a1:
    result[i] = []

for e in a2:
    splitted = e.split(",")
    c = 0

    for key,array in result.items():
        result[key].append(splitted[c])
        c = c+1
```

This requires many loops and assumes result.items() will always return the keys in the same order, which is [not a safe assumption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629023/the-order-of-keys-in-dictionaries).

Is there any way to avoid this? Maybe using Pandas?

Comment: Iterate over `a1` for your keys instead of `result.items()`.

Comment: Minor comment: in Python 3.7 onward, dictionaries are in fact guaranteed to preserve insertion order, as mentioned in the SO thread to which you link, and in the official docs (https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping).

Comment: Since you already figured out how to split the strings as you wish, your question here can be simplified by starting with `a2` as a 2D list instead of a list of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map`, `split`, numpy array transpose, `zip` and `dict`

```
n = np.array(list(map(lambda x: x.split(','), a2))).T.tolist()

Out[245]: [['1', '2', '3'], ['20', '10', '40'], ['300', '300', '300']]

result = dict(zip(a1, n))

Out[247]: {'a': ['1', '2', '3'], 'b': ['20', '10', '40'], 'c': ['300', '300', '3
00']}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from numpy import transpose

a1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
a2 = ["1,20,300", "2,10,300", "3,40,300"]
a2t = transpose([e.split(",") for e in a2])

result = {a1[i] : list(a2t[i]) for i in range(len(a1))}

=> {'a': ['1', '2', '3'], 'b': ['20', '10', '40'], 'c': ['300', '300', '300']}
```

thx to Code-Apprentice for the suggestion to use {x : y for ... }

Comment: This is a very clean answer. Alternatively, you can use a dict comprehension instead of calling the dict() constructor. And use `enumerate()` instead of `range()`.

Comment: i often struggle with creating dicts in one line so the dict() is my goto solution. how would dict comprehension work in a oneliner?

Comment: I'd do `{k: a2t[i] for i, k in enumerate(a1)}`. (Disclaimer: not tested)

Comment: Take this a step further with `zip()`: `{k: v for k, v in zip(a1, a2t)}`. But now we are back to an even shorter version with `dict()`: `dict(zip(a1, a2t))`. Someone else might have just jumped to this last version directly.

Comment: about the dict(zip(a1, a2t)) solution. the problem is you get numpy.array objects not lists. you would have to have another map function over it. i think the current code is most easy to unterstand

Comment: I think that is a problem in all of my solutions. The two dict comprehensions can be modified easily by converting each value to a list.

Comment: Generalizing an answer to your original question about a one liner: `dict([(x, y) for ...])` is equivalent to `{x: y for ...}`. Not only is this less typing, it is also more efficient at run time.

Answer (score 1):

Since you never use `array`, you don't need to call `result.items()` at all. Even `result.keys()` is problematic because, as you say, you can't rely on the order. So you need to iterate over `a1` instead. But you also need the index. You can count this yourself as you do in your solution. Or you can use `enumerate()` to generate it for you:

```
for c, key in enumerate(a1):
```

Alternatively, you can transpose your array (after calling split on each string). Then you can build your dictionary in a one-line comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

```
a1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
a2 = ["1,20,300", "2,10,300", "3,40,300"]
a2 = [item.split(',') for item in a2]

res = {}
for i in range(len(a1)):
    res[a1[i]] = [item[i] for item in a2]
res

{'a': ['1', '2', '3'], 'b': ['20', '10', '40'], 'c': ['300', '300', '300']}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if a2 also contains more strings like this ["1,20,300", "2,10,300", "3,40,300", "1,1,1"]

It's my bad I should have specified that in the question.

Comment: @Saturnix if a2 has more elements than a1 what do you want? if the length depend on a1, just swap a2 to a1 in for loop

Answer (score 1):

In case you want lists of integers as your output as you initial post suggests, you could do to the following:

```
dict(zip(a1, np.array([[int(j) for j in i.split(',')][:3] for i in a2]).T.tolist()))
```

Note that I used a slice in the inner loop to make sure that each element of a1 had the same length. This returns

```
Out[17]: {'a': [1, 2, 3, 1], 'b': [20, 10, 40, 20], 'c': [300, 300, 300, 300]}
```