# Python - How to double sort an array of objects following a specified order of the attributes?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a class of this type

```
class Challenge():
  difficulty = Field(type=float)
  category = Field(type=str)
```

and I have a list of Challenge objects that I want to sort in a custom way: I want to order by difficulty with a custom order, and then per each difficulty I want to sort the objects by category, with a different custom order per each difficulty.

I already have a dict with as keys the ordered difficulties, and for each difficulty the ordered list of categories. I need to apply this ordering to my list and I don't know how to apply those criteria to sorting.

I reached this point:

```
found_challenges.sort(key=lambda x: (x.difficulty, x.category))
```

Obviously this doesn't sort by the way I want to sort. How can I apply those custom criteria to list sorting?

Example:

```
ch_1 = Challenge(difficulty=1.0, category='one')
ch_2 = Challenge(difficulty=1.0, category='two')
ch_3 = Challenge(difficulty=2.0, category='one')
ch_4 = Challenge(difficulty=2.0, category='two')
```

and the ordering dictionary is

```
{
   2.0: ['one', 'two'],
   1.0: ['two', 'one']
}
```

so the ordering should be:

```
[ch_3, ch_4, ch_2, ch_1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there:

```
found_challenges.sort(key=lambda x: (-x.difficulty, ordering_dict[x.difficulty].index(x.category)))
```

So the second key is the index of the category in the respective difficulty list. If you want to reverse the order on that just add a `-` sign.

If your difficulties are not just monotonic, note [The order of keys in dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629023/the-order-of-keys-in-dictionaries). You can only depend on the insertion order from Python 3.7. In prior versions, if you want to index the keys you need an `OrderedDict`.

Comment: Done! I had also to respect the order of insertion of the keys of `ordering_dict` dictionary, so I achieved my purpose in this way:

`found_challenges.sort(key=lambda x: (list(ordering_dict.keys()).index(x.difficulty),
                                            ordering_dict[x.difficulty].index(x.category.value)))`