# python printing dictionaries in different order

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

Below is my code

```
qas = [
    ["Apple","Red"],
    ["Banana", "Yellow"],
    ["Berries","Blue"]
]
answer_choices = {
    "a" : "Red",
    "b" : "Yellow",
    "c" : "Blue"
}
Answers_count = 0

for qa in qas :
    print("Choose from")
    for k,v in answer_choices.items() :
        print("("+k+") "+" "+v)
    ans=input("\nWhat color is "+ qa[0]+" : ")
    if answer_choices.get(ans) == qa[1] :
        print("Correct \n")
        Answers_count += 1
    else :
        print("Wrong \n")
print("You got "+str(Answers_count)+" correct")
```

Answers are expected to be printed as (a), (b), (c)

Some how order in which answer choice key value pairs printing is changing with the order of keys in qas.

Please suggest

Comment: Dict keys follow insertion order only since CPython 3.6. You must be using an earlier Python version if that is not the case for you. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629023/the-order-of-keys-in-dictionaries for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Python dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) are not keeping the insertion order of the elements, it's not having a *lexicographic* ordering as well.
You can try using an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) in order to keep the **insertion order** (not *lexicographic* one).

Another suggestion will be to replace the `answer_choices` with a list of tuples where the first argument will be the answer key while the seconds one will be the choose.

```
answer_choices = [("a", "Red"), ("b", "Yellow"), ("c", "Blue")]
    for k,v in answer_choices:
        print("(" + k + ") " + " " + v)
```