# How to iterate through a list and print the key's in a specific order

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary

I'm trying to print out the keys of my grocery list in the same order they are written in the dictionary originally, this only helps me print the keys alphabetically.

Here is my code currently:

```py
grocery_list = {
    "name": "milk",
    "cost": "2.99",
    "quantity": "2",
}

for i in sorted(grocery_list.keys()):
    print(grocery_list[i])
```

Comment: [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: No, what I'm trying to achieve is printing name, cost, quantity in that order.

Comment: Stop using sorted. Python 3.6+ retains insertion order of dicts so unless you’re on and older version you’re sorting when you shouldn’t be for this case otherwise use OrderedDict.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1867861/11301900.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep keys/values in same order as declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, `dictionaries` were unordered containers, but recent `python` versions maintain insertion order so you can just do this for `python3.6+`:

```py
grocery_list = {
    'name': 'milk',
    'cost':'2.99',
    'quantity':'2'
}

for key, value in grocery_list.items():
   print(key, value, sep=': ')

>>> name: milk
>>> cost: 2.99
>>> quantity: 2
```

If you run an older `python` version, you have to somehow specify order, in this case is manual:

```py
ordered_keys = ['name', 'cost', 'quantity']

for key in ordered_keys:
    print(key, grocery_list[key], sep=': ')

>>> name: milk
>>> cost: 2.99
>>> quantity: 2
```

Comment: To be pedantic: this is only guaranteed on python 3.7 and beyond. The fact that it works on the 3.6 version of cpython is an implementation detail, and it is not guaranteed that every implementation of python 3.6 will behave this way.

Comment: @SethMMorton that's totally true!

Answer (score 0):

The keys are returned in arbitrary order, may be helpful to refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629023/the-order-of-keys-in-dictionaries).

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to use OrderedDict.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d1 = OrderedDict({
    'name': 'milk',
    'cost': '2.99',
    'quantity': '2'
})
print(d1.keys())
```

Answer (score 0):

For versions 3.6+, simply use `grocery_list.keys()` to get all the keys of your dictionary. It returns `dict_keys(['name', 'cost', 'quantity'])`
For older versions, you can use `OrderedDict`. This will retain the order of your dictionary.