# Swapping the first two keys of dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have the following dictionary, I want to swap 'path' and 'outputs', so that path appears first

```
 {'outputs': {'path': 'abc.jpg',
    'size': {'width': 1920, 'height': 1080, 'depth': 3},
    'object': [{'name': 'vehicle',
    'pose': 'Unspecified',
    'truncated': 0,
    'difficult': 0,
    'bndbox': {'xmin': 1532, 'ymin': 631, 'xmax': 1657, 'ymax': 687}},
     {'name': 'vehicle',
    'pose': 'Unspecified',
    'truncated': 0,
    'difficult': 0,
    'bndbox': {'xmin': 795, 'ymin': 685, 'xmax': 880, 'ymax': 723}},
     {'name': 'vehicle',
    'pose': 'Unspecified',
    'truncated': 0,
    'difficult': 0,
    'bndbox': {'xmin': 1473, 'ymin': 660, 'xmax': 1529, 'ymax': 690}}]}}
```

like this

```
{'path': 'abc.jpg','outputs': {
    'size': {'width': 1920, 'height': 1080, 'depth': 3},
    'object': [{'name': 'vehicle',
    'pose': 'Unspecified',
    'truncated': 0,
    'difficult': 0,
    'bndbox': {'xmin': 1532, 'ymin': 631, 'xmax': 1657, 'ymax': 687}},
     {'name': 'vehicle',
    'pose': 'Unspecified',
    'truncated': 0,
    'difficult': 0,
    'bndbox': {'xmin': 795, 'ymin': 685, 'xmax': 880, 'ymax': 723}},
     {'name': 'vehicle',
    'pose': 'Unspecified',
    'truncated': 0,
    'difficult': 0,
    'bndbox': {'xmin': 1473, 'ymin': 660, 'xmax': 1529, 'ymax': 690}}]}}
```

This dictionary is obtained by loading a json string. Is there some way of swapping the first two keys of this dictionary?

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629023/the-order-of-keys-in-dictionaries

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The order of keys in dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629023/the-order-of-keys-in-dictionaries)

Comment: Oh wait... they're at different nesting levels.  That's a different problem

Comment: If it is important to you in which order the keys are in a dictionary, you are doingsomething wrong. It is a mapping. It lets you get a value for a key. Use it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pop` to remove the `path` from withing `outputs` and create a new toplevel key `path` to store the removed value.

```
dict = json.loads(...)
dict["path"] = dict["outputs"].pop("path")
```

Note that it would place `path` to the same level as `output`, but it doesn't have to appear *first*, as keys of a dictionary are unordered.

Answer (score 2):

It's generally a sign that you are doing something you shouldn't, or your data should be organized differently, if you are depending on key order.  You may want to clarify your use case to see if there is a better way to achieve what you are trying to do, or a better practice.  That said:

Reference: [The order of keys in dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629023/the-order-of-keys-in-dictionaries)
For Python 3.7.0+, insertion order is preserved and in the specs.
For Python 3.6+, insertion order is preserved, but only as an implementation detail.
For < 3.6 you will want to use `collection.OrderedDict`

Re-insert attributes to get the order right for 3.6+:

```
data={'outputs': {'path': 'abc.jpg',
    'size': {'width': 1920, 'height': 1080, 'depth': 3},
    'object': [{'name': 'vehicle',
    'pose': 'Unspecified',
    'truncated': 0,
    'difficult': 0,
    'bndbox': {'xmin': 1532, 'ymin': 631, 'xmax': 1657, 'ymax': 687}},
     {'name': 'vehicle',
    'pose': 'Unspecified',
    'truncated': 0,
    'difficult': 0,
    'bndbox': {'xmin': 795, 'ymin': 685, 'xmax': 880, 'ymax': 723}},
     {'name': 'vehicle',
    'pose': 'Unspecified',
    'truncated': 0,
    'difficult': 0,
    'bndbox': {'xmin': 1473, 'ymin': 660, 'xmax': 1529, 'ymax': 690}}]}}

data['path'] = data['outputs']['path']
del data['outputs']['path']
data['outputs'] = data.pop('outputs')
```

`collections.OrderedDict` for < 3.6.  Only difference is that the dict is wrapped in OrderedDict before re-inserting:

```
data={'outputs': {'path': 'abc.jpg',
    'size': {'width': 1920, 'height': 1080, 'depth': 3},
    'object': [{'name': 'vehicle',
    'pose': 'Unspecified',
    'truncated': 0,
    'difficult': 0,
    'bndbox': {'xmin': 1532, 'ymin': 631, 'xmax': 1657, 'ymax': 687}},
     {'name': 'vehicle',
    'pose': 'Unspecified',
    'truncated': 0,
    'difficult': 0,
    'bndbox': {'xmin': 795, 'ymin': 685, 'xmax': 880, 'ymax': 723}},
     {'name': 'vehicle',
    'pose': 'Unspecified',
    'truncated': 0,
    'difficult': 0,
    'bndbox': {'xmin': 1473, 'ymin': 660, 'xmax': 1529, 'ymax': 690}}]}}

from collections import OrderedDict
data = OrderedDict(data)

data['path'] = data['outputs']['path']
del data['outputs']['path']
data['outputs'] = data.pop('outputs')
```

This is basically just like @choroba's answer, just with detailed explanation and re-insertion to re-arrange key order.

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed answer. choroba answered first so I had to accept his answer.  Your observations are correct about this dictionary. I am swapping this because of a third party tool requiring json to be formatted exactly that way. Otherwise, it does not work and I had to rely on that. Thanks again.