# How to multiple key list values in two dictionaries

Tags: python

E.g I have the following

`d1 = {'a': [100,300,34], 'b': [200,98,45], 'c':[450,567,300]}`

`d2 = {'d': [300,500,234], 'e': [300,500,234], 'f':[300,500,234]}`

Want to get

`d3 = {'ad': [400,800,268], 'be': [500,598,279], 'cf':[750,1067,534]}`

I have the following in mind to start:
`for i, j in d1.items():`
`for x, y in d2.items():`

Comment: Depending on your Python version, that may not be well defined, because the order of keys (until 3.7) is unspecified. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629023/the-order-of-keys-in-dictionaries

Comment: I mean in python 2.5

Answer (score 1):

Here, I use a nested comprehension to achieve what you want. First, I take corresponding items in `d1` and `d2` using `zip()`. Then, I concatenate their keys, making that the key of the new dict, and use a list comprehension to sum the elements of their respective lists, which gets set as the value in the new dict.

```
d3 = {
        i1[0] + i2[0]: [v1 + v2 for v1,v2 in zip(i1[1], i2[1])]
        for i1,i2 in zip(d1.items(), d2.items())
    }
# {'ad': [400, 800, 268], 'be': [500, 598, 279], 'cf': [750, 1067, 534]}
```

Note that, before Python 3.7, the 'order' of a dict was arbitrary. Now, when you call `.items()`, you'll get keys in the order they were most recently added or defined, but before that you could get them in any order, and so the above would not work.

Comment: Can I do that with Python 2.5 instead, im using python 2.5 on spss modeller

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
d3 = {k1 + k2: [p + q for p, q in zip(d1[k1], d2[k2])] for k1, k2 in zip(d1.keys(), d2.keys())}
```

or

Without using dictionary comprehension:

```
d3 = {}
for k1, k2 in zip(d1.keys(), d2.keys()):
    d3[k1 + k2] = [p + q for p, q in zip(d1[k1], d2[k2])]
```

Output:

```
{'ad': [400, 800, 268], 'be': [500, 598, 279], 'cf': [750, 1067, 534]}
```

Make sure to use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html?highlight=ordereddict#collections.OrderedDict) if you want to maintain the order of the keys.

Comment: Thanks, I am actually trying to do that with for loop outside the dictionary.

Comment: How can I do that without dictionary comprehensions im using python 2.5 inside spss modeler which does nor support dict comprehensions