# How to fix key order of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dataframe below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name":["Jack","Joe","Al","Al","Joe","Jack","Jack"],"X1":[1,4,6,5,7,9,2]})
```

I made a different dataframe for each value in the "Name" column.

```
dic = {}
k=1
for i in set(df.Name):
    dic[k] = df.loc[df.Name == i]
    dic[k].reset_index(inplace=True)
    dic[k].drop(columns="index",inplace = True)
    k += 1
```

Now keys are "Jack","Joe" and "Al", values are dataframes.

But keys order change every time when I run the code. Is there any way to fix key order?

Comment: Have you seen this topic here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629023/the-order-of-keys-in-dictionaries .

Comment: before python 3.6 dict is unordered collection. And in 3.6. order-preserving is implementation detail and should not be relied upon.  It looks like you run version before 3.6. Use `OrderedDict` from collections.

Comment: @buran my version is 3.7.7.

Comment: sorry, I overlooked you apply `set()` on `df.Name` set is unordered collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries are not for ordering by keys. Use OrderedDict instead:

```
import collections
ordered = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(dic.items()))
```

Comment: Dicts were unordered before python 3.6. And in 3.6. order-preserving is implementation detail and should not be relied upon. Starting from 3.7 order is preserved