# how to sort part of a dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary like this:

```
dic = {'jack':15,'sara':'20','bob':13,'abby':13}
```

I only want to sort the keys that have similar values just like 'bob' and 'abby'.
I need to get this output:

```
dic = {'jack':15,'sara':'20','abby':13,'bob':13}
```

Comment: A Python dictionary is not an ordered data type, so there is no way to determine the order of the keys here. You're probably looking for something like Python's [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: What is the reason for needing to sort them? Quite often if you find yourself wanting the sort a dictionary then it means you might actually want a different data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach where you can create an inverted dictionary first and then insert back in a `sorted()` manner.

Since the dictionaries [maintain insertion order by default from Python3.6+](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-dict-implementation), you can be sure that they keys are in ordered manner. Read more about dictionary keys ordering in [the order of keys in dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629023/the-order-of-keys-in-dictionaries).

```
dic = {'jack':15,'sara':20,'bob':13,'abby':13}
invertedDic = {}
for k, v in dic.items():
    invertedDic.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
    
dic = {}
for key, val in invertedDic.items():
    for v in sorted(val):
        dic[v] = key
```

Having said that as Kemp pointed, you should look at the requirement of ordering and probably a different data structure might be better suited for storing the data.

You could also have a look at [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) as Paul pointed depending on the requirement.