# How to select keys from a dictionary by their order?

Tags: python, dictionary

Sorry this is probably very simple, but I suspect I'm wording the question wrong from inexperience so I haven't been able to find the answer anywhere.

I have a dictionary, e.g.:

`dict = {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}`

I want to select specific values within the dictionary from knowing only their position in the dictionary.

For example I want to print the first key, and all I know about the key is that it's the first key in the dictionary, not its actual name to call on.

I am trying:

```
dict[0][0]
```

And I'm expecting this to output `1`, the first key in the dictionary - but I'm not experienced in python so I'm not sure how to get this working?

Comment: Depending on your python version, the dictionary may or may not be ordered by insertion order. I think it is guaranteed for python 3.7+ and accidentally the case for 3.5&3.6. Dictionaries don't support direct indexing though

Comment: Indexing was the word I needed to know to do a much better job googling this problem - thank you for this!! Good to know I can't do it directly so I can try something else, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40007169/913098) is probably what you were looking for.

Note this is for Python 3.7 and forward.

```
d = {1: 'a', 2: 'b'} # dict is a bad variable name! don't do it! it overrides a built-in!
d_keys = list(d.keys())
first_value = d[d_keys[0]]
```

Comment: Thank you for this, didn't realise about the dict thing either - will keep that in mind going forward, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries cannot be used like lists, in that you *cannot* refer to their position. However, you can use something like this to get the keys from your dictionary:

```
my_dict = {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}

for k in my_dict:
    print(k)
    print(my_dict[k])
```

Output:

```
1
a
2
b
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to get all keys by `keys()` method then take first key which is *1* this:

```py
dict = {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}
keys = list(dict.keys())
print(keys[0]) #1
```

Answer (score 1):

There's not any builtin method to access key or values within a dictionary via indexes. But you can achieve your desired outcome by converting the dictionary to **list of list** via `list comprehension`.

```
dictt = {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}
dict_items = [[k,v] for k,v in dictt.items()]
print(dict_items)
>> [[1, 'a'], [2, 'b']]
```

If you want first key in the dictionary

```
print(dict_items[0][0])
>> 1
```

If you want first value in the dictionary

```
print(dict_items[0][1])
>> a
```

If you want second key in the dictionary

```
print(dict_items[1][0])
>> 2
```

If you want second value in the dictionary

```
print(dict_items[1][1])
>> b
```