# How to efficiently get an arbitrary item from a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, time-complexity

I am doing some graph theory and I use the NetworkX library.

In some algorithms, one needs to get an arbitrary item from a dictionary to start it (for instance, one of the neighbors of a given node, and the neighborhoods are a dict in NetworkX).

By *arbitrary element* I mean any element, I don't care which one (not a given element, not a random element, etc.)

Currently I do the following:

```
D = {i:i**2 for i in range(N)}  # an example of a dictionary where N is a positive integer
any_item_of_D = list(D)[0]      # getting a item of D
```

But it appears that the time complexity of `any_item_of_D = list(D)[0]` is linearly growing as N tends to infinity (a O(N) complexity).

Is it possible to get an arbitrary item from a dictionary with a O(1) complexity in Python?

Comment: It's not clear if you really mean `arbitrary item` from the dict, or if you are looking for a `random item` from the dict. It think you will find `D[next(iter(D.keys()))]` to give constant time *arbitrary* elements.

Comment: you can use ordereddict to get fist item in O(1)

Comment: Mark: as written in my question, I am looking for an arbitrary item, not a random item. But thanks you for your answer, it seems to work :)

Comment: leaf_yakitori: NetworkX does not use ordereddict.

Comment: Have you tried converting it to set instead of a list?

Comment: I do not understand how you interpret the term "arbitrary". Do you mean something like getting the value pointed by the `i`th key in the dictionary?  Of course, assuming the dictionary preserves the keys in insertion-order: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40007169/937153

Comment: pyNeophyte: but how do you get an arbitrary item from a set in O(1) ?

Comment: Unni: by arbitrary I mean any element, I don't care which one.

Comment: @Mark That is only O(1) for an OrderedDict, for a std dict that is O(n) in worst-case.

Comment: Hi @wim...this is a pretty old thread. I wonder if you could clarify the worst-case. What is the case where `D[next(iter(D.keys()))]` is O(n)?  Where does the linear behavior come from?

Comment: @Mark It comes from the possibility that you have to skip past a bunch of "empty markers" left from items which have been removed from the dict

Comment: @wim...sorry if I'm being slow. Are you saying `next(iter(D.keys()))` will possibly have to iterate over a bunch of values — like `keys()` produces values for deleted items? Or is there some performance case in dicts where `D[some_key]` has to skip a bunch of 'markers'? I've honestly never heard of "empty markers" in this context?

Comment: @Mark When you delete an item from a dict, it doesn't (usually) shift or resize the underlying data storage, it just puts an empty marker into that position. So in iterating a dict, at each step of the iteration you have to check for possibility of an empty 'tombstone' left from where there was an item in the dict but it's now deleted, and skip over those. You can see that in CPython [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/424dfc723137fb1ca8f3b5e4eb12ba3e669a9f52/Objects/dictobject.c#L4079-L4082). To get the _O(n)_ case for `next(iter(D.keys()))`, create big dict then remove n items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pop item returns an arbitrary item in *O(1)*, which you can then put back into the dict (also *O(1)*).

```
key, val = D.popitem()
D[key] = val
```

Since Python 3.7 [LIFO order is guaranteed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.popitem) for `dict.popitem`, so you don't have to worry about it messing up ordering either.

This is significantly faster than creating an item iterator just to get the first item:

```
>>> timeit k,v = D.popitem(); D[k] = v
107 ns ± 0.0716 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
>>> timeit next(iter(D.items()))
164 ns ± 0.0687 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Note that `next(iter(ordered_dict))` is *O(1)* but `next(iter(std_dict))` [can be *O(n)* in worst-case](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/424dfc723137fb1ca8f3b5e4eb12ba3e669a9f52/Objects/dictobject.c#L4079-L4082).

Answer (score 0):

I have "always" done `next(iter(D.items()))`, but to be honest, I have never checked whether it is the most efficient way...