# Why iteration on dict will change keys order in output?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is python ordering my dictionary like so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526125/why-is-python-ordering-my-dictionary-like-so)

Why iteration on this dict

```
d = {'tors':None,
     'head':None,
     'armr':None,
     'arml':None,
     'legl':None,     
     'legr':None}

for k in d.keys():
    print k
```

will output keys in different order:

```
head
legl
armr
arml
tors
legr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
import collections

ordered_d = collections.OrderedDict([('banana', 3),('apple',4),('pear', 1),('orange', 2)])
for k in ordered_d.keys():
    print k
```

with the result:

```
banana
apple
pear
orange
```

Answer (score 6):

In python `dict` is implemented as hash map and nobody can't guarantee keys order. From documentation

> CPython implementation detail: Keys and values are listed in an
>   arbitrary order which is non-random, varies across Python
>   implementations, and depends on the dictionary’s history of insertions
>   and deletions.

If you need to keep ordering, use `collections.OrderedDict` instead.

Comment: Thank you. But another question. Maybe will suggest different struct to keep values? I access like this: eg `self.body[key]['pos']`.