# Merging two dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I need help merging two dictionaries. I can merge them but the problem is I need the two dictionaries to maintain their order.

For expample:

```
x = {'a':1, 'b': 2}
y = {'b':10, 'c': 11}
z = dict(x.items() + y.items())
print z
```

{'a': 1, 'c': 11, 'b': 10}

This output is a problem. I need the output to be: `{'a':1, 'b':10, 'c': 11}`
The order of the letters must be maintained.

Comment: The dictionaries are unorderred. What you want is unattainable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is python ordering my dictionary like so?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526125/why-is-python-ordering-my-dictionary-like-so)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The base Python dictionary class is unordered. You'll need to use [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead, if you're on 2.7 or 3.anything, or one of the many implementations you can find easily with Google for 2.6 or earlier. Here's one recipe that the Python docs link to for 2.4-2.6: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576693/

Comment: so i would have to do "import collections" then x = collections.OrderedDict{'a':1, 'b':2} ?

Comment: If you want to control the order, you have to give the `OrderedDict` an iterable of key/value pairs, or add them after creating it. Something like: `x = collections.OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2)])`. Or `x = collections.OrderedDict(); x['a'] = 1; x['b'] = 2`.