# Can I make Django QueryDict preserve ordering?

Tags: python, django, http, query-string

Is it possible to to make Django's QueryDict preserve the ordering from the original query string?

```
>>> from django.http import QueryDict
>>> q = QueryDict(u'x=foo³&y=bar(potato),z=hello world')
>>> q.urlencode(safe='()')
u'y=bar(potato)%2Cz%3Dhello%20world&x=foo%C2%B3'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict) class is based on [`MultiValueDict`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/datastructures.py#L282) class that is based on regular python `dict`, which is an unordered collection as you know.

According to the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2bcb8bfc8de5cd57ebb64b326cd7609aa0d8c1c7/django/http/request.py#L283), `QueryDict` internally uses [`urlparse.parse_qsl()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qsl) method, which preserves the order of query parameters, outputs a list of tuples:

```
>>> from urlparse import parse_qsl
>>> parse_qsl('x=foo³&y=bar(potato),z=hello world')
[('x', 'foo\xc2\xb3'), ('y', 'bar(potato),z=hello world')]
```

What you can do, is to use the order of keys given by the `parse_qsl()` for sorting:

```
>>> order = [key for key, _ in parse_qsl('x=foo³&y=bar(potato),z=hello world')]
>>> order
['x', 'y']
```

Then, subclass `QueryDict` and override `lists()` method used in `urlencode()`:

```
>>> class MyQueryDict(QueryDict):
...     def __init__(self, query_string, mutable=False, encoding=None, order=None):
...         super(MyQueryDict, self).__init__(query_string, mutable=False, encoding=None)
...         self.order = order
...     def lists(self):
...         return [(key, self.getlist(key)) for key in self.order]
... 
>>> q = MyQueryDict(u'x=foo³&y=bar(potato),z=hello world', order=order)
>>> q.urlencode(safe='()')
u'x=foo%C2%B3&y=bar(potato)%2Cz%3Dhello%20world'
```

The approach is a bit ugly and may need further improvement, but hope at least it'll give you an idea of what is happening and what you can do about it.

Answer (score 3):

[`QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict) inherits from Django's [`MultiValueDict`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.7.x/django/utils/datastructures.py#L282) which inherits from `dict` which is [implemented as a hash table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/526131/3096768). Thus, you can't guarantee it will stay ordered.

I'm not sure if this will be relevant to what you need, but [an ordering that QueryDict does preserve is the order of "lists" (multiple values for the same key) passed in to them](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.lists). Using this, you could do:

```
>>> from django.http import QueryDict
>>> q = QueryDict(u'x=foo³&x=bar(potato),x=hello world')
>>> q.lists()
[('x', ['foo³', 'bar(potato)', 'hello world'])]
>>> q.urlencode(safe='()')
u'x=foo%C2%B3&x=bar(potato)&x=hello%20world'
```

Comment: this behavior changed after python 3.7, could you update your answer?   https://stackoverflow.com/a/47837132/13953019