# Why doesn't OrderedDict use super?

Tags: python, oop, multiple-inheritance, super, python-collections

We can create an `OrderedCounter` trivially by using multiple inheritance:

```
>>> from collections import Counter, OrderedDict
>>> class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict): 
...     pass
...
>>> OrderedCounter('Mississippi').items()
[('M', 1), ('i', 4), ('s', 4), ('p', 2)]
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but this crucially relies on the fact that [`Counter` uses `super`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/761d139852063b9aa3caf58023184c4a399d594f/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L533):

```
class Counter(dict):
    def __init__(*args, **kwds):
        ...
        super(Counter, self).__init__()
        ...
```

That is, the magic trick works because

```
>>> OrderedCounter.__mro__
(__main__.OrderedCounter,
 collections.Counter,
 collections.OrderedDict,
 dict,
 object)
```

The `super` call must delegate according to 'siblings before parents' rule of the [mro](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/), whence the custom class uses an `OrderedDict` as the storage backend.

However a colleague recently pointed out, to my surprise, that `OrderedDict` [doesn't](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/761d139852063b9aa3caf58023184c4a399d594f/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L107-L119) use super:

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value,
                dict_setitem=dict.__setitem__, proxy=_proxy, Link=_Link):
    ... 
    # <some weird stuff to maintain the ordering here>
    dict_setitem(self, key, value)
```

At first I thought it could be because `OrderedDict` came first and Raymond didn't bother to change it later, but it seems that `super` predates `OrderedDict`.

**Why does `OrderedDict` call `dict.__setitem__` explicitly?**

And why does it need to be a kwarg?  Doesn't this cause trouble when using `OrderedDict` in diamond inheritance situations, since it passes directly to the parent class instead of delegating to the next in line in the mro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a microoptimization. Looking up a `dict_setitem` argument is slightly faster than looking up `dict.__setitem__` or `super().__setitem__`.

This might cause problems with multiple inheritance if you have another class that overrides `__setitem__`, but `OrderedDict` isn't designed for that kind of diamond-structured method overriding anyway. For `OrderedDict` to support that, it'd have to make very careful guarantees about what another class's methods might see if they try to index the `OrderedDict` while the ordering information is inconsistent with the dict structure. Such guarantees would be way too messy to make.

Comment: Django's `QueryDict` overrides `__setitem__`, and the `collections.OrderedDict` does not do cooperative inheritance.  Example of a problem caused by this "micro-optimization":  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23662247/can-i-make-django-querydict-preserve-ordering#comment78727560_41798570