# Order of traversal in dictionary

Tags: python

When I access the elements in 2 dictionaries that are mapped using the same keys, do they get accessed in the same order at all times?

For example, say I have dictionary 1 and dictionary 2.

```
Dictionary 1:
Key 1: a1
Key 2: a2

Dictionary 2:
Key 1: b1
Key 2: b2
```

If I access the elements of these 2 dictionaries using a for loop, using something like this:
`for element in dictionary.values():`

Can I then match up `a1:b1` and `a2:b2`?

Comment: If they have identical keys, just iterate over one's keys then get the values from both for that key. Why rely on order?

Comment: I am fairly certain that you can count on the fact that 2 successive calls to dict.values() without any other call on that dict will yield the same result. But that is not a feature of the dict, it just so happens because there is no reason for anything else to happen

Comment: Essentially: consider dictionaries to be completely without order. Pretend every call to `__iter__` returns `random.choice(self.keys())` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such guarantee.

Here is a concrete example that demonstrates this:

```
>>> dict1 = {str(i):None for i in range(10000)}
>>> dict2 = {}
>>> dict2.update(dict1)
```

The dictionaries are equal but the keys are returned in different order:

```
>>> dict1 == dict2
True
>>> dict1.keys() == dict2.keys()
False
```

If you want the same traversal order, you could parallel iterate over `sorted(dict1.keys())` and `sorted(dict2.keys())`:

```
>>> sorted(dict1.keys()) == sorted(dict2.keys())
True
```

Depending on your use case (i.e. the insertion order), [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) might also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

[Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) in python are without order. For a datatype that keeps order: use a [list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#).

From the official python docs:

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value
>   pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one
>   dictionary).

For more information on why are they unordered, check out this answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/526131/2259303

Answer (score 0):

You're not guaranteed any ordering in a dictionary.

But you can get sorted key, value pairs in lists of tuples. For instance:

```
chars = {'a':0, 'c':2, 'f':6, 'h':8}
sorted_chars = sorted(chars.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)) 
# list of tuples sorted by value => [('a', 0), ('c', 2), ('f', 6), ('h', 8)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to impose some order to your dictionaries.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d1 = OrderedDict([('ka1','a1'), ('ka2','a2')])
d2 = OrderedDict([('kb1','b1'), ('kb2','b2')])

for k1, k2 in zip(d1, d2):
    print d1[k1], d2[k2]
```

will print out:

```
a1 b1
a2 b2
```