# Preserve order in dict when reading from csv

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have .csv file, I want to csv convert to dict. 
Below my code:

```
testo = []
with open('dTest.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        testo.append(row) 
print testo[4]
teo = json.dumps(testo[4])
```

My .csv file:

```
c2:9f:db:67:12:48   c2:9f:db:e7:85:ad   06:27:22:fd:6b:50
      -67                 -51                 -110
```

But my dictionary results is random:

```
{u'c2:9f:db:e7:85:ad': u'-51', u'c2:9f:db:67:12:48': u'-67',u'06:27:22:fd:6b:50': u'-110'}
```

I want my dictionary result is not random:

```
{u'c2:9f:db:67:12:48': u'-67', u'c2:9f:db:e7:85:ad': u'-51', u'06:27:22:fd:6b:50': u'-110'}
```

Comment: What do you mean random?

Comment: the structure is different from my .csv file @StephenRauch

Comment: dictionaries are unordered containers. That means that the information stored within a dictionary is not ordered. So you can't ask for `row[2]`, but you can ask for `row['c2:9f:db:67:12:48']`. If you want an ordered container, you're better off with a `list` (`csv.reader` instead of `csv.DictReader`). If you really _really_ want an ordered dictionary, you could try something with `collections.OrderedDict`, but you'd have to put in some effort to read your csv files with such a structure

Comment: If upgrading your Python version is an option, [Python 3.6's `csv.DictReader` is documented](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) as returning instances of `OrderedDict` rather than normal `dict` instances which don't have any particular order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to preserver order within a dict you can use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict
testo = []
with open('dTest.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    headers = next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        testo.append(OrderedDict(zip(headers, row)))

print(testo[0])
```

this is guaranteed to always have this output:

```
OrderedDict([('c2:9f:db:67:12:48', '-67'), ('c2:9f:db:e7:85:ad', '-51'), ('06:27:22:fd:6b:50', '-110')])
```

Other than the order, an `OrderedDict` has the same properties as a normal `Dict` so you can e.g. loop over it with `for key in test[0]`

Answer (score 1):

As of Python 3.6, dictionaries will preserve their insertion order: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2016-September/146327.html

> A nice "side effect" of compact dict is that the dictionary now
>   preserves the insertion order.

It is a "side effect", however, and not in the official spec so its probably not guaranteed to always work that way in future versions.

Comment: The docs for the `csv.DictReader` class have actually been updated to say that it returns `OrderedDict` instances, so for this specific situation, relying upon the order is guaranteed to be supported even on implementations of Python where normal dictionaries are still unordered.

Comment: With Python 3.8+ the docs now indicate that a dict is returned - not an OrderedDict -https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html  Be mindful of this - while this is the accepted answer it is not valid for newer versions of Python

Answer (score 0):

By definition, dictionaries in Python are **not ordered**, so you cannot maintain (or rely on) any specific ordering of the elements you grab from the CSV file.

[Why is python ordering my dictionary like so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526125/why-is-python-ordering-my-dictionary-like-so)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you want. By definition, [dictionaries in Python are unordered](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). As the documentation says,

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one dictionary).

Whether the entry is accomplished by reading a file or typing in on the keyboard, Python does not care what order you enter the key-value pairs into the dictionary, as long as each key is unique. The key-value pairs will be stored in arbitrary order.

Why is this? It's because dictionaries are stored in a hash table. The unique key is hashed and the key-value pair is stored at the resultant location. A good enough hash algorithm should be *designed* for the hash value to be unpredictable. So the desire to keep the dictionary sorted by key all the time is antithetical to the way a dictionary is built.