# Python Dictionary Key Order With Comprehensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, for-loop

I'm messing around with dictionaries for the first time and something's coming up that's confusing me. Using two lists to create a new dictionary, the order of the list terms for the key part seems to be wrong. Here's my code:

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
list2 = [5,3,7,3] 
newDict = {list1[c]: number for c, number in enumerate(list2)}
print(newDict)
```

This gives me the following:

```
{'a': 5, 'd': 3, 'c': 7, 'b': 3}
```

Why is this happening? Surely the 'c' value getting terms from the list is going from 0 and upwards, so why isn't it creating the dictionary with the letters in the same order?

Thanks.

Comment: dictionaries are unordered data-structures.

Comment: Note also, you could just use `dict(zip(list1, list2))`

Comment: Prior to version `3.6` [Dictionaries are unordered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6)

Comment: Usually I would, but this is for a Physics assignment that doesn't want us to use content we haven't been officially taught yet. That's why I'm using dictionaries at all actually. Thanks though.

Comment: @bro-grammer technically, in Python 3.6, the fact that dictionaries preserve insertion order is an implementation detail. It will be a part of the spec in versions >= 3.7

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, I have also posted the linked question which describe this behaviour in details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For purposes of efficiency, traditional python dictionaries are unordered.  If you need order, then you need `OrderedDict`:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> newDict = OrderedDict((list1[c], number) for c, number in enumerate(list2))
>>> print(newDict)
OrderedDict([('a', 5), ('b', 3), ('c', 7), ('d', 3)])
```

[In Python 3.7](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html), ordinary python dictionaries, implemented using a new algorithm, will be ordered.  Until then, if you need order, use `OrderedDict`.

Comment: What makes you think they need that? They're only asking why it doesn't preserve order, not saying they want to.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Under normal rules of human behavior, the OP wouldn't take the time to ask about order unless, for some reason, it mattered to him.

Answer (score 1):

Python dictionaries don't preserve their order, but there's another data type that does: OrderedDict, from the collections module.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are unordered. In fact, if you run your program on a different computer, you might get a different key ordering. This is an intentional feature of the built-in dictionary in python.

To understand why, take a look at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526125/why-is-python-ordering-my-dictionary-like-so).

Answer (score 0):

As of Python 3.7, dictionaries are **insertion ordered**.
See this stackoverflow discussion [Are dictionaries ordered in Python 3.6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39980323/601770)